# How to align Text within Graphics?

Tags: plotting, graphics, text, alignment, inset

Consider the code

```
lin = Graphics[{Red, Line[{{0.5, 0}, {0.5, 1}}]}];
rect = Graphics[{Rectangle[], 
    Inset[Style[Text["aaa"], 20, White, Bold, 
      TextAlignment -> Left]]}];
Show[rect, lin]
```

[image]

I want to start writing from left to right after the red line (or at a given $x$ position), that is

[image]

and so that when I had more letter, it writes on the right:

[image]

How do I do this? I've tried playing around with `TextAlignment` or `TextJustification` with no success.

Comment: `Graphics[{Rectangle[], Red, Line[{{0.5, 0}, {0.5, 1}}], Text[Style["aaa", 20, White, Bold], {0.5, 0.5}, {-1.2, 0}]}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to `Inset[]` the following arguments : `, Center, {Left, Center}` :

```
lin = Graphics[{Red, Line[{{0.5, 0}, {0.5, 1}}]}];
rect = Graphics[{Rectangle[], Inset[
     Style[Text["aaabbb"], 20, White, Bold(*,TextAlignment\[Rule]Left*)]
     , Center, {Left, Center}
     ]}];
Show[rect, lin]
```

[image]